# Difference between make(map) and map{}

Tags: go

Just wondering what the difference is between:

```
z := make(map[*test] string)
```

and

```
z := map[*test] string{}
```

am I imagining things or are they both not valid?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Making slices, maps and channels](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)
>
> The built-in function make takes a type T, which must be a slice, map
>   or channel type, optionally followed by a type-specific list of
>   expressions. It returns a value of type T (not *T). The memory is
>   initialized as described in the section on initial values.
>
> ```
> Call         Type T  Result
> make(T)      map     map of type T
> make(T, n)   map     map of type T with initial space for approximately n elements
> ```
>
> [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and
>   maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They consist
>   of the type of the literal followed by a brace-bound list of elements.
>   Each element may optionally be preceded by a corresponding key.
>
> ```
> map[string]int{}
> map[string]int{"one": 1}
> ```

---

`make` is the canonical form. Composite literals are a convenient, alternate form.

```
z := make(map[int]string)
```

and

```
z := map[int]string{}
```

are equivalent.

Comment: Succinct response. What then is the difference between 

```var z map[int]string```
```z := map[int]string{}``` (which is equivalent to ```z := make(map[int]string)```

Comment: From what I understand, there is a slight difference. The code var z map[int]string will generate nil, where both the other two codes z := make(map[int]string) and z := map[int]string{} will generate an empty slice. These three can be used in range loop and etc but you are able to still detect the difference in them if required.

Answer (score 12):

Function `make()` and initializer of empty map are identical.

> The same syntax may be used to initialize an empty map, which is
>   functionally identical to using the make function:
>
> `m = map[string]int{}`

from https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Using pointer as map key is valid as pointer is [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

Although, remember that values these pointers point to are not checked:

> Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they
>   point to the same variable or if both have value nil. Pointers to
>   distinct zero-size variables may or may not be equal.